# Using simple future and future perfect

Tags: grammar, future-time

What is the difference between the following sentences

1. At 6 o'clock I will have left. = The action of leaving will be complete by 6:00.
2. By 6 o'clock I will have left. = The action of leaving will be complete by 6:00.

Now to me they both mean the same, but, there is a difference of preposition, so there must be some difference between them, like there is when we use

a) At 6 o'clock I will leave. = The action of leaving will begin at 6:00.

b) By 6 o'clock I will leave. = The action of leaving will be before 6:00.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> At 6 o'clock I will leave/have left.

This means: I will leave/have left at exactly 6 o'clock.

> By 6 o'clock I will leave/have left.

This means: I will leave/have left at 6 o'clock **at the latest**, but probably before that. I'm not sure when exactly I will leave. But I will have left until 6.

Comment: So does 'I will have left at 6 o'clock' mean I will not leave before 6 o'clock? Am I right?

Comment: You wouldn't say that. "will have left" indicates the process of leaving, which is not a point in time.

Comment: @shikha ji: "I will have left by x" means you will be gone at x because you left some time before. Either seconds or hours before x, but at x you are gone.

Comment: @someasw Can't "I will have left by x" mean I will leave at x? because by definition, 'by' means either before or at. So is it not possible to leave at x? This is confusing.

Comment: @shikha ji: Yes, "I will have left by x" might also mean "I will leave at x". But you would rather use it to express that you will leave some time BEFORE x (hence using "by"). If you want to express that you will leave exactly at x, you say "I will leave at x".

Comment: @someasw: Does by the time X, mean at X or before X? If it can mean before X, then can 'I will be eating pizza by 5 p.m.' mean I am eating before 5 p.m. and not at 5 p.m.?

Comment: @shikha ji: Yes, "by" means "before or at". In this case, "at x" means a specific point x in time, whereas "by x" in this case means "before or at x, but not later than x".

Comment: @someasw, you have not addressed the second part of my question, can 'I will be eating pizza by 5 p.m.' mean I am eating before 5 p.m. and not at 5 p.m.?

Comment: @shikha ji: It's all in my previous comment.